# Have the ODBC excel BigQuery connector support the new M1 macs?

Tags: google-bigquery

Just got the BigQuery driver set up for my installation of excel on my 2016 mac. But when I did the same set up on my coworker's new m1 mac he got an error saying that the driver doesn't support the m1 architecture. I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find anything mentioning using ODBC with BigQuery and the new mac architecture.

Would love an update on this!

Comment: Can you edit the post and include the exact error message? At what part of the installation did you encounter the error? Can you please add more details.

Comment: We found a work around, so we don't have the exact error message. But the error said that the driver does not work on m1 macs, Now I'm just curios if the drivers every going to support m1 macs

Comment: You can post your workaround as an answer and accept it, so the solution is visible and will help others who encounter this problem in the future!

Comment: You can contact Simba support with regards to this issue since they provide the ODBC driver for BigQuery https://www.magnitude.com/about-us/contact

Comment: Its not really a solution, hes just using a different computer

Comment: Just to add new Macs uses M1 processors which implements ARM architecture while the old Macs implements the x86 architecture. The website doesn't show any links with regards to ARM drivers thus the suggestion to submit a ticket to Simba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted support, connector support for new m1 macs is coming Q1 of 2022.

Comment: Just to confirm is it 2021 or 2022? Since we are past already Q1 of 2021?

Comment: Yeah, just fixed it.